# SLLN applies to last $r_n$ variables?

Tags: probability, self-study, convergence

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of IID random variables with finite mean and first moment, let $S_n = \sum_1^n X_n $ then is it true that 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{S_n - S_{n-r_n}}{r_n} 
\end{equation}
converges almost surely to the mean if $\liminf \frac{r_n}{n} > 0$? Basically we're taking the latest $r_n$ variables and averaging them. What's a way to show this? Also, apparently without the condition it fails, even if $\lim r_n = \infty $, I can't think of a counterexample because I can't even show this.

Comment: I suspect $S_n = \sum_i^n X_i$ for some r.v.s $X_i$? Whether true or not, please clarify.

Comment: What happens if $r_n = n^2$, or $r_n = n$?

Comment: Yes thank you that is $S_n$. I'm trying to prove this somehow and provide a counter example when $r_n$ doesn't grow fast enough.

Comment: As it stands, considering the two cases I asked about above ought to convince you it's not true even if $\lim \inf r_n / n >0$.

Comment: This obviously is not true--take $r_n=n-1$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\ne 0$ for an easy counterexample--but perhaps there's a typographical error, since the formula does not match its description.  Perhaps you are asking about $(S_n - S_{n-r_n})/r_n$ instead?

Comment: What distinction are you attempting to draw between the "mean" and the "first moment"? Ordinarily these are considered synonymous, so perhaps there's another typographical slip involved there, too.

Comment: _"Basically we're taking the latest $r_n$ variables and averaging them"_

This sounds like an always _finite_ sum of variables. If this is the case, there are no asymptotics here.

Comment: @Alecos Your conclusion is incorrect. *All* asymptotic statements ultimately refer only to finite sets of variables.  Look at any definition of convergence of a sequence (in any sense): it always refers only to a finite segment of the sequence, never to the entire infinite sequence as a whole. That idea--being able to deal within infinities by means of propositions about finite sets--is perhaps *the* key idea introduced into mathematical analysis in the last two centuries.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the correction, these are still matters that I am learning. Still, I can only understand the verbal description of the OP as "consider a sum that is comprised of a _fixed_ number of variables", i.e. that $r_n$ does not increase but remains a fixed number (do I understand "the latest $r_n$ variables" part correctly?). If this is the OP's case, can I take, say, $r_n=2$? And if I can do that, how can I reach asymptotic conclusions? My initial comment related to such a situation.

Comment: @Alecos You can indeed reach asymptotic conclusions when $r_n=2$: but you must conclude that convergence of the tail average is not guaranteed, that's all.  However, if (say) $r_n = 1+\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor$ then $r(n)$ is *always* finite for all $n$, but now convergence of the tail averages to the mean will occur. This is the critical distinction between *bounded* (the first case) and *finite* (the second).

Answer (score 4):

**It is true.**  In fact, it suffices only to assume that $n-r(n)$ diverges.

---

There's a meta-theorem lurking here, so allow me at the outset to be vague both about the form of convergence and even about what is converging.  Suppose we are given a countable sequence  $(X_i)=X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n, \ldots$ of mathematical objects with the following minimal properties:

1. *They can be averaged*.  Specifically, for $0\le m \lt n$ let

   $$S_{m,n} = (X_{m+1} + X_{m+2} + \cdots + X_n) / (n-m)$$

   be a "partial average" between $m$ and $n$.
2. *Their averages converge:* $S_n \to \mu$ as $n\to \infty$.
3. *They are "self-similar"* in the sense that any property of the sequence also holds for any tail sequence $(Y_i)$ where $Y_i = X_{m+i}$ and $m \ge 0$.  (In particular, this means that if the tail averages of the $X_i$ converge to $\mu$ at a certain rate, then the tail averages of the $Y_i$ also converge to $\mu$ *at the same rate.*)

Let $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ be the non-zero natural numbers and suppose $r: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ for which $r(n) \lt n$ for all $n$.  **The question asks about the convergence of $S_{r(n), n}$.**  Let's see what might be needed to make that happen.

About the only effective way to analyze these partial averages is to **break up the sums:**

$$\eqalign{
n S_n &= n(X_1 + \cdots + X_n)/n \\
      &= (X_1 + \cdots + X_r(n)) + (X_{r(n)+1} + \cdots + x_n) \\
      &= r(n) S_{r(n)} + (n-r(n)) S_{r(n), n}.
}$$

Upon rearranging we may solve for the tail average:

$$S_{r(n), n} = \frac{n S_n - r(n)S_{r(n)}}{n - r(n)}.$$

**This can give us trouble if the denominator remains small.**  Suppose, though, that $n - r(n) \to \infty$: that is, for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $n_0$ such that $n-r(n) \gt N$ for all $n\ge n_0$.  It's easy to see that in this circumstance the right hand side will also converge to $\mu$, because

- $S_n\to \mu$.
- $S_{r(n^\prime)} \to \mu$ for any subsequence $n^\prime$ for which $r(n^\prime)\to\infty$.
- $\frac{r(n^\prime)}{n^\prime-r(n^\prime)}S_{r(n^\prime)}\to 0$ and $\frac{n^\prime - r(n^\prime)}{n^\prime-r(n^\prime)}S_{n^\prime}\to \mu$ for any subsequence $n^\prime$ for which $r(n^\prime)$ remains bounded.

Conversely, if $n-r(n)$ has a bounded infinite subsequence $n^\prime$, then all bets are off: $S_{r(n^\prime), n^\prime}$ is a sequence of tail averages involving a *bounded* number of the $X_i$ and the assumptions (1) - (3) do not allow us to infer anything about them.  Almost any sequence that does not exactly *equal* its limit after a finite number of elements would serve as a counterexample.

It is therefore apparent that the proper condition to invoke (because it is both necessary and sufficient for convergence of the tail averages) is the assumption that $n-r(n)$ diverges: this will suffice to guarantee the convergence of $S_{r(n), n}$ to $\mu$.  This is a weaker condition than $\lim\inf \frac{r(n)}{n} \gt 0$ (which clearly implies the divergence of $r(n)$). Consider, for instance, the sequence $r(n) = \lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$.  For this sequence, $r(n)$ diverges but $r(n)/n$ converges to zero.

Providing the detailed steps for a sequence of iid random variables and almost sure convergence is now a purely mechanical exercise, which I leave to the reader (because this is a [self-study](/questions/tagged/self-study) question).